# Call method of main form from other class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm wondering what is the cleanest way to call a method which modifies mainForm, from a subform method.

I want to keep mainForm disabled until an initial subform has finished. Now I have simply passed the mainForm object to the subform and the subform does mainForm.Enabled = true and closes itself when finished. Isn't it rather inelegant to pass the entire mainForm like that? Os is that how it's done?

Comment: No, you shouldn't let forms dig in each other's internals. Apply a design pattern such as MVVM or simple events, where a `FooHappened` event has the result of enabling a form.

Comment: When you show the subform set the main form's enabled property to false, and when the subform is closing, set the main form's enabled property to true.

Comment: A cleaner way would be using an Interface: your main form should implement an interface with a property `Enable` (because it seem that you have a new behaviour for this property) and the other specific methods you need for this new behaviour. And then you can pass the interface instead of mainForm to your subform.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
Application.OpenForms[0]
```

You can get the instance of your main window (cast as mainwindow type). If you make your method public, you can call the method or property public you can call it from a second window.

**Edit:**

You need to reference

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

to access the `Application` object.

Answer (score -1):

You can expose the Enabled poperty of mainForm:

```
public bool FormEnabled{
    get{ return this.Enabled;}
    set{ this.Enabled = value;}
}
```

Comment: The property is already public, right? So why wrap it in another property?